# How to stop loop in AutoIt?

Tags: autoit

How to exit or not from a while loop?

This is the code:

```
Global $test

$choice = GUICreate("Custom MsgBox", 225, 80)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please select a button.", 10, 10)
Local $idYess = GUICtrlCreateButton("YES", 10, 50, 65, 25)
Local $idNoo = GUICtrlCreateButton("NON", 80, 50, 65, 25)
Local $idExitt = GUICtrlCreateButton("EXIT", 150, 50, 65, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $choice)

Local $iMsgBoxAnswer = 1, $bLoop = True

While $bLoop
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $idYess
            ConsoleWrite("$idYess=" & $idYess & @CRLF)

        Case $idNoo
            ConsoleWrite("$idNoo=" & $idNoo & @CRLF)

    EndSwitch

    If $iMsgBoxAnswer = 1 Then ContinueLoop

    $iMsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox(4100, "MsgBox", "Are you sure you want to close the program?", 3)
    Select
        Case $iMsgBoxAnswer = 6 ;Yes
            ConsoleWrite("- bye bye" & @CRLF)
            $bLoop = False
    EndSelect
WEnd 
      
Global $num = 1    
    
While 1
                                            
  Switch $num
    Case "1"
        MsgBox(0, '', 'Number 1')
        ExitLoop 
  EndSwitch
Wend
```

Why isn't the 2nd working?

And why does it work after have click on exit on first loop?

Comment: Your link is invalid, but we don't allow code in external links anyway. Please take a few minutes to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how this site works, and then [edit] your post to provide your code here, in the question itself, clearly explain the problem you're having with that code, and ask a **specific question** related to that code, so that we can try to help.

Comment: You need to follow the links I gave you before. If you had done so, you would have seen [mre], which requires you to post the code here, reduced to the fewest number of lines needed to demonstrate the issue. Again, we don't allow code in external links. You still have not taken the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how SO works., Doing so will greatly improve your experiences here.

Comment: See, where `ContinueLoop` continues and where `$iMsgBoxAnswer` gets changed.

Comment: It works because you do not start the 2nd loop until you left the 1st loop. Your program flow is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>


$choice = GUICreate("Custom MsgBox", 225, 80)
GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please select a button.", 10, 10)
Local $idYess = GUICtrlCreateButton("YES", 10, 50, 65, 25)
Local $idNoo = GUICtrlCreateButton("NON", 80, 50, 65, 25)
Local $idExitt = GUICtrlCreateButton("EXIT", 150, 50, 65, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $choice)

Local $iMsgBoxAnswer = 1

While 1
    Switch GUIGetMsg()
        Case $idYess
            ConsoleWrite("$idYess=" & $idYess & @CRLF)
            _reallyExit()
        Case $idNoo
            ConsoleWrite("$idNoo=" & $idNoo & @CRLF)

        Case $idExitt
            ConsoleWrite("$idExitt=" & $idExitt & @CRLF)
            _reallyExit()
    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func _reallyExit()
    $iMsgBoxAnswer = MsgBox(4100, "MsgBox", "Are you sure you want to close the program?", 3)
    If $iMsgBoxAnswer = $IDYES Then
        ConsoleWrite("- bye bye" & @CRLF)
        Exit
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>_reallyExit
```